# PhoneGap How to add plugin which is not in npm

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

on my application, I have a config.xml file and use  https://build.phonegap.com/apps  website to build native application.
For plugins I hav used setting like ,

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
```

Now I need to access a plugin for which I have the files (i.e. that plugin is not in npm or any other publically assessiable location)

How can I include that on my config file?
Any idea ?

Comment: please put plugin in any directory in your system i preffer same directory/folder where your project is and then fire command in your project like `cordova plugin add ../yourpluginname`

Comment: @Naitik , I don't use cordova command line tool, I have a config.xml

Answer (score 0):

The `<plugin>` element in the `config.xml` file supports other means of referring to the plugin via the `spec` attribute:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#plugin

Also, here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#plugin-spec

I currently point to a git repo in one of my plugin test apps, but I think something like @Naitik mentions would also be valid in the `config.xml` file:

```
<plugin name="yourplugin" spec="../yourpluginname">
```

---

EDIT: I see you are using PhoneGap Build. Local plugins won't work there -- the free account only allows NPM plugins. I'm not sure how the paid account works, but it does look like they have "private plugins." Not sure how those work.